# How to handle users who keep logging out and in with Firebase Phone Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Some of my users keep logging out and in several times using Firebase Phone Auth. The reason seems they have multiple phone numbers but only want to install the app on one device. Multiple phone numbers will enable them to have multiple accounts with my app.

Since there is a limitation of 10k/month, how to handle these kind of users?

Comment: Hi, what your app does? Why don't you just allow them to add multiple phone number to the same account and create an special form to add anche connect them and use it? so they dont need to log out, will be better for them and for you, no multiple account/password, more clear use of the app

Comment: To avoid the students of doing fraud, I only allow one phone number per account.